# myString.replace( VARIABLE, "") ...... but globally

Tags: javascript, string, variables, replace

How can I use a variable to remove all instances of a substring from a string?
(to remove, I'm thinking the best way is to replace, with nothing, globally... right?)

if I have these 2 strings,

```
myString = "This sentence is an example sentence."
oldWord = " sentence"
```

then something like this

```
myString.replace(oldWord, "");
```

only replaces the first instance of the variable in the string.

but if I add the global g like this `myString.replace(/oldWord/g, "");` it doesn't work, because it thinks oldWord, in this case, is the substring, not a variable. How can I do this with the variable?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you pass a variable to a Regular Expression JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/494035/how-do-you-pass-a-variable-to-a-regular-expression-javascript)

Answer (score 94, accepted):

**Well, you can use this:**

```
var reg = new RegExp(oldWord, "g");
myString.replace(reg, "");
```

**or simply:**

```
myString.replace(new RegExp(oldWord, "g"), "");
```

Comment: Boom: `var oldWord = '\\';`

Answer (score 12):

You have to use the constructor rather than the literal syntax when passing variables. Stick with the literal syntax for literal strings to avoid confusing escape syntax.

```
var oldWordRegEx = new RegExp(oldWord,'g');

myString.replace(oldWordRegEx,"");
```

Comment: Woot! Is that copying from me?

Comment: I just type slower and offer more advice.

Comment: Sigh... always a bridesmaid never an answer.

Answer (score 7):

No need to use a regular expression here: split the string around matches of the substring you want to remove, then join the remaining parts together:

```
myString.split(oldWord).join('')
```

In the OP's example:

```js
var myString = "This sentence is an example sentence.";
var oldWord = " sentence";
console.log(myString.split(oldWord).join(''));
```

Answer (score -2):

According to the docs at MDN, you can do this:

```
var re = /apples/gi;
var str = 'Apples are round, and apples are juicy.';
var newstr = str.replace(re, 'oranges');
console.log(newstr);  // oranges are round, and oranges are juicy.
```

where /gi tells it to do a global replace, ignoring case.

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: The question is about replacing the content of a variable