# javascript string.replace(var1, var2)

Tags: javascript, string, variables, replace

I have found plenty of questions that almost answer my question, for example this [myString.replace( VARIABLE, "") ...... but globally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10136097/mystring-replace-variable-but-globally/) but they all lack one detail.

I want to do something like this

```
var clipText = "aaabccc";
var replaceStr = "abc";
var withStr = "def";
clipText = clipText.replace(/replaceStr/g, withStr);
```

That is, use two variables as arguments to `replace` but `replace` seems to interpret the variable names literally rather than using their assigned value. I also want to replace all occurrences, hence the `g` after `replaceStr`.

What gives?

Comment: @quentin Please explain how the linked question applies to my situation. I don't need a regexp.

Comment: `/replaceStr/g` is a regexp!!

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [**`RegExp`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) constructor function:

```js
var clipText = "aaabccc";
var replaceStr = "abc";
var withStr = "def";
var regex = new RegExp(replaceStr,"g");
clipText = clipText.replace(regex, withStr);
console.log(clipText);
```

Comment: Do I *need* to use a regexp in my situation? I have no problems doing it but it seems just very ad-hoc that `replace` only accepts literal strings, not variables containing literal strings!?!?

Comment: @d-b, if you want to use variable then you have to use `new RegExp()`, though you can directly use the text like... `clipText.replace(/abc/g, withStr);`:)

Comment: But abc in your example is not a variable?

Comment: @d-b, that is what I am trying to say, if you put the text (*abc*) in a variable then you have to use `new RegExp()`:)

Comment: That is just weird. It deserves its own question. Does even Perl work like that (i.e., a string without quotations or similar is treated like a string rather than a variable)??